# Extracting Arabic/Persian text from PDF in java

Tags: java, pdf, io, converters

I want to extract a PDF document that contains Arabic and Persian text. Is there any Java API that can output Arabic or Persian from PDF file as Java String to proceed further?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: There are APIs to extract text from PDF's.  Look at iText or pdfbox.

Comment: @usr169 that depends more on the PDF itself than on the library

Comment: No idea.  Write code.  Have a look.

Comment: I tried Arabic as well as Persian but displaying strange characters. Its working fine for English